# Is there a benefit to destructuring when using require?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there any performance advantage or disadvantage (when using `require`) to importing the entire module, versus importing only selected functions?

As I understand it when using `require` to import modules (as opposed to using `import` ) compilers such as Babel do not perform any pruning of the final code as it does when using `import`. As such, considering then that both methods end up providing pointers to functions. I'm wondering if there is any reason to prefer one over the other. Or if this is just a matter of personal preference and readability.

```
const { methodOne, methodTwo } = require('../myLibrary')
const x1 = methodOne()
const x2 = methodTwo()
```

VS

```
const Lib = require('../myLibrary')
const x1 = Lib.methodOne()
const x2 = Lib.methodTwo()
```

> I'm not looking for opinions on one style versus the other, I think both have value in certain situations. I'm just trying to figure out if there even is a technical reason to prefer one over the other.
> Also for now let's just assume I'm not using Node 14 so `import` is not available.

Comment: No difference at all, apart from style

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any performance advantage or disadvantage (when using require) to importing the entire module, versus importing only selected functions?

No.  The entire module is loaded either way.  It's only a matter of which exports you choose to save within your module so you can use them.

> As I understand it when using require to import modules (as opposed to using import ) compilers such as Babel do not perform any pruning of the final code as it does when using import.

Correct.  There is no pruning with `require()` or with `import`.  Basically nodejs doesn't do pruning - entire modules are loaded or not.  Pruning would
have to be done by something like a bundler or packager that can rewrite/reorganize the code before it is fed to nodejs and physically remove code that isn't being referenced.

> As such, considering then that both methods end up providing pointers to functions. I'm wondering if there is any reason to prefer one over the other.
> Or if this is just a matter of personal preference and readability.

Just personal preference.

> I'm not looking for opinions on one style versus the other, I think both have value in certain situations. I'm just trying to figure out if there even is a technical reason to prefer one over the other.

No technical reason to prefer one over the other.